# Converting an integer to binary strings in c

Tags: c, binary, int

This is what I've tried, my logic is that my `tmp` shifting left 31 times will get compared to the user input integer `I` and a value of 1 or 0 will be inserted to index `str[0]` -> `str[31]` and the I null terminate `str[32]` with the `\0`.

However, I'm getting a segmentation fault.

P.S. I'm not allowed to change the parameters of this function and my professor set the size of `str` to be 33 in the main, which, I'm not allow to change either.

```c
void int2bitstr(int I, char *str) {
        int tmp = 1 << 31;
        do{
                *str++ = !!(tmp & I) + '0';
        } while(tmp >>= 1);
        *str = '\0';
}
```

Comment: `int` is signed. Have you forgotten about it?

Comment: I always use [Valgrind](https://www.valgrind.org) to understand segfaults

Comment: Building on what Eugene said, I think you would be surprised at your output if you print the value of `tmp` to your console with each iteration, especially in consideration of your loop-exit clause.

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset I got the program to work, I'm actually new to c and never heard of valgrind; thankyou for your suggestion, I'll keep it in mind!

Answer (score 1):

Try making `tmp` an `unsigned int`. The behaviour of right-shifting a negative (signed) integer is implementation-defined, and in your case is likely shifting in 1s (the original MSB) thus causing the loop to exceed the length of `str`.

Comment: `int tmp = 1 << 31;` --> `unsigned tmp = 1u << 31;`  (be sure to change to `1u`)

Comment: Thank you! The program works fine now, I can't believe I forget about this